# how to write a scheme program consumes n and sum as parameters, and show all the numbers(from 1 to n) that could sum the sum?

Tags: algorithm, lisp, scheme

How to write a scheme program consumes n and sum as parameters, and show all the numbers(from 1 to n) that could sum the sum? Like this:

（find 10 10）

> > ((10) 
> >     (9 , 1) 
> >     (8 , 2) 
> >     (7 , 3) 
> >     (7 ,2 , 1) 
> >     (6 ,4) 
> >     (6 , 3, 1) 
> >     (5 , 4 , 1) 
> >     (5 , 3 , 2) 
> >     (4 ,3 ,2 ,1))

I found one:

```
(define (find n sum) 
  (cond ((<=  sum 0) (list '())) 
        ((<= n 0) '()) 
        (else (append 
                 (find (- n 1) sum) 
                 (map (lambda (x) (cons n x)) 
                  (find (- n 1) (- sum n)))))))
```

But it's inefficient,and i want a better one. Thank you.

Comment: The `find` procedure posted doesn't work. Test it with `(find 10 10)`, the output is different from the one in the question, and some of the answers don't even add to `10`. See my answer for a correct implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to, but not exactly like, the [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) problem or the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem. It's not the integer partition problem, because an integer partition allows for repeated numbers (here we're only allowing for a single occurrence of each number in the range).

And although it's more similar to the subset sum problem (which can be solved more-or-less efficiently by means of dynamic programming), the solution would need to be adapted to generate all possible subsets of numbers that add to the given number, not just one subset as in the original formulation of that problem. It's possible to implement a dynamic programming solution using Scheme, but it'll be a bit cumbersome, unless a matrix library or something similar is used for implementing a mutable table.

Here's another possible solution, this time generating the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the range `[1, n]` and checking each subset in turn to see if the sum adds to the expected value. It's still a brute-force approach, though:

```
; helper procedure for generating a list of numbers in the range [start, end]
(define (range start end)
  (let loop ((acc '())
             (i end))
    (if (< i start)
        acc
        (loop (cons i acc) (sub1 i)))))

; helper procedure for generating the power set of a given list
(define (powerset set)
  (if (null? set)
      '(())
      (let ((rest (powerset (cdr set))))
        (append (map (lambda (element) (cons (car set) element))
                     rest)
                rest))))

; the solution is simple using the above procedures    
(define (find n sum)
  (filter (lambda (s) (= sum (apply + s)))
          (powerset (range 1 n))))

; test it, it works!
(find 10 10)
=> '((1 2 3 4) (1 2 7) (1 3 6) (1 4 5) (1 9) (2 3 5) (2 8) (3 7) (4 6) (10))
```

**UPDATE**

The previous solution will produce correct results, but it's inefficient in memory usage because it generates the whole list of the power set, even though we're interested only in *some* of the subsets. In Racket Scheme we can do a lot better and generate only the values as needed if we use lazy sequences, like this (but be aware - the first solution is still faster!):

```
; it's the same power set algorithm, but using lazy streams
(define (powerset set)
  (if (stream-empty? set)
      (stream '())
      (let ((rest (powerset (stream-rest set))))
        (stream-append
         (stream-map (lambda (e) (cons (stream-first set) e))
                     rest)
         rest))))

; same algorithm as before, but using lazy streams
(define (find n sum)
  (stream-filter (lambda (s) (= sum (apply + s)))
                 (powerset (in-range 1 (add1 n)))))

; convert the resulting stream into a list, for displaying purposes
(stream->list (find 10 10))
=> '((1 2 3 4) (1 2 7) (1 3 6) (1 4 5) (1 9) (2 3 5) (2 8) (3 7) (4 6) (10))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I try the one using lazy sequences but it still seems too long for (find 100 100). With c++ it would be better. I think there may be a better one. Thanks again.

Comment: A more efficient solution is possible if we completely change the algorithm, using dynamic programming, but it's a lot trickier. It won't be much faster if you use a different language! Please consider accepting the most useful answer by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you are looking for is known as an [integer partition](http://www.google.com/#q=integer+partition). I have a couple of implementations at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com).

**EDIT:** Oscar properly chastized me for my incomplete answer. As penance, I offer this answer, which will hopefully clarify a few things.

I like Oscar's use of streams -- as the author of [SRFI-41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41) I should. But expanding the powerset only to discard most of the results seems a backward way of solving the problem. And I like the simplicity of GoZoner's answer, but not its inefficiency.

Let's start with GoZoner's answer, which I reproduce below with a few small changes:

```
(define (fs n s)
  (if (or (<= n 0) (<= s 0)) (list)
    (append (if (= n s) (list (list n))
              (map (lambda (xs) (cons n xs))
                   (fs (- n 1) (- s n))))
            (fs (- n 1) s))))
```

This produces a list of the output sets:

```
> (fs 10 10)
((10) (9 1) (8 2) (7 3) (7 2 1) (6 4) (6 3 1) (5 4 1) (5 3 2) (4 3 2 1))
```

A simple variant of that function produces the count instead of a list of sets, which shall be the focus of the rest of this answer:

```
(define (f n s)
  (if (or (<= s 0) (<= n 0)) 0
    (+ (if (= n s) 1
         (f (- n 1) (- s n)))
       (f (- n 1) s))))
```

And here is a sample run of the function, including timings on my ancient and slow home computer:

```
> (f 10 10)
10
> (time (f 100 100)
(time (f 100 ...))
    no collections
    1254 ms elapsed cpu time
    1435 ms elapsed real time
    0 bytes allocated
444793
```

That's quite slow; although it is fine for small inputs, it would be intolerable to evaluate `(f 1000 1000)`, as the algorithm is exponential. The problem is the same as with the naive fibonacci algorithm; the same sub-problems are re-computed again and again.

A common solution to that problem is memoization. Fortunately, we are programming in Scheme, which makes it easy to encapsulate memoization in a macro:

```
(define-syntax define-memoized
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (f args ...) body ...)
      (define f
        (let ((results (make-hash hash equal? #f 997)))
          (lambda (args ...)
            (let ((result (results 'lookup (list args ...))))
              (or result
                  (let ((result (begin body ...)))
                    (results 'insert (list args ...) result)
                    result)))))))))
```

We use [hash tables](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/#hash-tables) from my [Standard Prelude](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude) and the [universal hash function](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/23/universal-hash-function/) from my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com). Then it is a simple matter to write the memoized version of the function:

```
(define-memoized (f n s)
  (if (or (<= s 0) (<= n 0)) 0
    (+ (if (= n s) 1
         (f (- n 1) (- s n)))
      (f (- n 1) s))))
```

Isn't that pretty? The only change is the addition of `-memoized` in the definition of the function; all of the parameters and the body of the function are the same. But the performance improves greatly:

```
> (time (f 100 100))
(time (f 100 ...))
    no collections
    62 ms elapsed cpu time
    104 ms elapsed real time
    1028376 bytes allocated
444793
```

That's an order-of-magnitude improvement with virtually no effort.

But that's not all. Since we know that the problem has "optimal substructure" we can use dynamic programming. Memoization works top-down, and must suspend the current level of recursion, compute (either directly or by lookup) the lower-level solution, then resume computation in the current level of recursion. Dynamic programming, on the other hand, works bottom-up, so sub-solutions are always available when they are needed. Here's the dynamic programming version of our function:

```
(define (f n s)
  (let ((fs (make-matrix (+ n 1) (+ s 1) 0)))
    (do ((i 1 (+ i 1))) ((< n i))
      (do ((j 1 (+ j 1))) ((< s j))
        (matrix-set! fs i j
          (+ (if (= i j)
                 1
                 (matrix-ref fs (- i 1) (max (- j i) 0)))
             (matrix-ref fs (- i 1) j)))))
    (matrix-ref fs n s)))
```

We used the [matrix functions](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/#matrices) of my [Standard Prelude](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude). That's more work than just adding `-memoized` to an existing function, but the payoff is another order-of-magnitude reduction in run time:

```
> (time (f 100 100))
(time (f 100 ...))
    no collections
    4 ms elapsed cpu time
    4 ms elapsed real time
    41624 bytes allocated
444793
> (time (f 1000 1000))
(time (f 1000 ...))
    3 collections
    649 ms elapsed cpu time, including 103 ms collecting
    698 ms elapsed real time, including 132 ms collecting
    15982928 bytes allocated, including 10846336 bytes reclaimed
8635565795744155161506
```

We’ve gone from 1254ms to 4ms, which is a rather astonishing range of improvement; the final program is O(*ns*) in both time and space. You can run the program at http://programmingpraxis.codepad.org/Y70sHPc0, which includes all the library code from my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com).

As a special bonus, here is another version of the `define-memoized` macro. It uses a-lists rather than hash tables, so it's very much slower than the version given above, but when the underlying computation is time-consuming, and you just want a simple way to improve it, this may be just what you need:

```
(define-syntax define-memoized
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((define-memoized (f arg ...) body ...)
      (define f
        (let ((cache (list)))
          (lambda (arg ...)
            (cond ((assoc `(,arg ...) cache) => cdr)
            (else (let ((val (begin body ...)))
                    (set! cache (cons (cons `(,arg ...) val) cache))
                    val)))))))))
```

This is a good use of quasi-quotation and the `=>` operator in a `cond` clause for those who are just learning Scheme. I can't remember when I wrote that function -- I've had it laying around for years -- but it has saved me many times when I just needed a quick-and-dirty memoization and didn't care to worry about hash tables and universal hash functions.

This answer will appear [tomorrow](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/05/24/coin-change-part-3/) at my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com). Please drop in and have a look around.

Comment: It's not _really_ the integer partition problem. In the solution to that problem, it's possible to have several repetitions of the same number that add up to the answer. In the sample output provided by the OP, there's only a single occurrence of each number, for a given subset.

Comment: I know. I was only giving a pointer to help him get started. That's also why I didn't write any code. Clearly there is a dynamic programming solution lurking here.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. And your blog is useful.

Comment: I added a proper answer after Oscar shamed me into it. Please take another look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is *generally* correct except you don't handle the `(= n s)` case.  Here is a solution:

```
(define (find n s)
  (cond ((or (<= s 0) (<= n 0)) '())
        (else (append (if (= n s)
                          (list (list n))
                          (map (lambda (rest) (cons n rest))
                               (find (- n 1) (- s n))))
                      (find (- n 1) s)))))

> (find 10 10)
((10) (9 1) (8 2) (7 3) (7 2 1) (6 4) (6 3 1) (5 4 1) (5 3 2) (4 3 2 1))
```

I wouldn't claim this as particularly efficient - it is not tail recursive nor does it memoize results.  Here is a performance result:

```
> (time (length (find 100 100)))
running stats for (length (find 100 100)):
    10 collections
    766 ms elapsed cpu time, including 263 ms collecting
    770 ms elapsed real time, including 263 ms collecting
    345788912 bytes allocated
444793
>
```

Comment: The solution seems to work well in the (= n s) case.But not efficient.

Comment: Famous quote "Premature optimization if the root of all evil" Donald Knuth.  I added a performance result - `(find 100 100)` finds 444793 results in 0.770 seconds.  If you really needed to improve the performance, you would memoize the intermediate result.  Before recursing, you would look for a prior result with `[n, s]` and use that prior result.